# Is there a formula for finding pressure as a function of depth in the ocean?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, geophysics, oceanography

It is well known that one can find the pressure in a static fluid as a function of height using the well-known formula for hydrostatic equilibrium
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}z}=-\rho g, \tag 1$$
where we can find $\rho$ using models. For example, if we are considering the atmosphere, then it is reasonable to assume that $\rho$ and $P$ are related via the ideal gas law: $P=\rho \bar{R}T$ and $T$ is related to the height $z$ via the formula $T=T_0-Bz$. Inserting all of this on the equation above and solving the resultant differential equation gives the so-called barometric formula
$P(z)=P_0~\bigg (1-\frac{Bz}{T_0} \bigg)^{\frac{g}{\bar{R}B}} \tag 2$.

While sometimes the constant-density formula $P=P_0+\rho g(z_0-z)$ works in the ocean, the density of seawater is not constant and therefore there are certainly situations in which variation in density cannot be neglected, as noted in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seawater#Density):

> The density of surface seawater ranges from about 1020 to 1029 $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$, depending on the temperature and salinity. At a temperature of 25 °C, the salinity of 35 g/kg and 1 atm pressure, the density of seawater is 1023.6 $\mathrm{kg/m}^3$.[[7]](https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.desal.2016.02.024)[[8]](http://web.mit.edu/seawater) Deep in the ocean, under high pressure, seawater can reach a density of 1050 $\mathrm{kg/m^3}$ or higher. The density of seawater also changes with salinity. Brines generated by seawater desalination plants can have salinities up to 120 $\mathrm{g/kg}$.

Taking this into account, I would like to know if there is a theoretical formula that, analogous to (1), allows us find pressure in the ocean at any given depth $z$ and that takes into account the variation of the density of seawater. What would the relation between $\rho$ and $P$ be in the case of seawater?

Comment: The problem here is that temperature and salinity have different profiles in different locations: there is to my knowledge no standard formula for a standard profile. Especially salinity can wobble quite a bit, although the density profile tends to be fairly smooth.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Are you telling me that such formula cannot exist?

Comment: [Example of spatiotemporal variation that generally precludes a better option than numerically integrating $P(z)=\int\rho(z)g(z)\,dz$ at the intended time and location.](https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/phod/docs/Wang_etal_2010_CD.pdf)

Comment: In case the link provided in the previous comment is broken, its DOI is http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00382-009-0560-5